# Python Playwright Automation Stops When VDS Connection is Closed

Tags: python, virtual-machine, rdp, playwright-python

I have an issue with running some automations using Python Playwright on a virtual dedicated server (VDS). The problem is that when I close the connection to the VDS, the automation script stops. I've tried reopening the VDS from another one, but the issue persists – the script stops when the connection is closed. Is there any solution to keep it running independently of the connection status? It only continues when I reconnect. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

*I cant use headless.*